# SCP alternative to copy file from one unix host to another unix host

Tags: unix

Have below constraints to copy file from one host to another unix host
1) Target host dont have ftp installed
2) scp is very slow for file in gigs

Is there any alternative option to copy file in less time , currently it is taking 90 hrs to copy 3 gigs file with scp

Comment: I don't know as SCP should not be slow. You could simply curl it from a webserver? curl -O http://server.domain.com/file.tgz

Answer (score 5):

Faster alternatives to scp are bbcp, gzip+nc or pigz+nc.

This link describes all the commandos in detail and why scp is slow:
http://intermediatesql.com/linux/scrap-the-scp-how-to-copy-data-fast-using-pigz-and-nc/

Here is a short summary of the commands used in the link.

bbcp:

```
bbcp -P 10 -f -T 'ssh -x -a %I -l %U %H bbcp' /u02/databases/mydb/data_file-1.dbf remote_host:/u02/databases/mydb/data_file-1.dbf
```

gzip+nc:

```
tar -cf - /u02/databases/mydb/data_file-1.dbf | gzip -1 | nc -l 8888
nc <source host> 8888 | gzip -d | tar xf - -C /
```

pigz+nc:

```
tar -cf - /u02/databases/mydb/data_file-1.dbf | pigz | nc -l 8888
nc <source host> 8888 | pigz -d | tar xf - -C /
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I added a short summary of the commands used in the link. @Larme

Comment: The link is showing up  as a malicious website warning for me.